# JavaScript: document.createNode or plain html?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it better to use

```js
document.createNode();
```

or plain text like

```js
var foo = '<div> bar </div>';
```

to create HTML markup with JavaScript?

Comment: Better for what? Readability? Performance? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "better" in this particular case, it is going to boil down to what is most easily maintained. and programmer preference.

In some browsers, using DOM to create elements and nodes is, in terms of performance, faster than others. Some user agents process strings faster, for example by setting the `innerHTML` property.

I personally prefer to use DOM objects always, but I use the mootools framework which lends itself to this approach. jQuery encourages string-based creation.

Check out this benchmark: http://jsperf.com/string-vs-createelement/3, but also consider these articles: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml_old.html and http://karma.nucleuscms.org/item/101

Comment: **NB**: innerHTML has been included in the DOM specification from the W3C only with HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use the DOM node functions. If you want to create it using a string, look into jQuery, as it has ways to parse it correctly into DOM nodes for you.

```
var foo = $('<div> bar </div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using DOM manipulation functions you can have a reference to the created elements, one by one, and will be easier to modify the code later on, for example modify the tree order, adding or removing an element, and also for debugging purposes.

This said, there are some times I experienced myself in which the DOM manipulation functions are not the best way.

For example I had the necessity to modify real time the content of a style tag, to control the style of the elements directly via text css rules, something you can't achieve in all browsers using the various JS style objects, because they contain read-only properties.

In this case the style tag html was read-only for IE (or at least IE didn't like to modify it via innerHtml or similar), the only solution I found was to read the old html value, change it, remove the element and create a new style tag element with the new html directly typed in the string when creating the element.

This said, I would go with the DOM node functions whenever possible.